# cUrl как и с помощью чего отправить это

Tags: php, curl, instagram, instagram-api, php-curl

я вожусь с Api instagram'a и в гайде написано, что:
"Откройте инструмент командной строки или приложение, которое поддерживает запросы cURL, и отправьте следующий POSTзапрос в API."

curl - X POST \ 
  https : //api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token \ - F client_id = 684477648739411 \
   - F client_secret = eb8c7 ... \
   - F grant_type = код авторизации \
   - F redirect_uri = https : // socialsizzle. herokuapp.com/auth/ \ - F code = AQDp3TtBQQ

Не совсем понимаю, как и в чем это сделать.

Answer (score -1):

cURL - юниксовая консольная программа. Есть виндовс версии, в виндовс10 с каким-то из обновлений она уже является встроенной в консоль (cmd)

https://levashove.ru/how-to-install-curl-on-windows-10/